# Pegar parâmetro passado por POST com $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

Estou com dificuldade em pegar o id passado pelo data do ajax (jquery), o que acontece é que utilizando `$_POST['id']` ou `filter_input(INPUT_POST,'id')` fica vazio

segue o ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "cursos/area/",
    dataType:'JSON',
    data:JSON.stringify ({'id': idArea}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            console.debug(result);
        }
})
```

e no PHP simplesmente estou tentando exibir pra testar

```
var_dump($_POST['id'])
```

Tentei encontrar outras formas de passar o data, pois acredito ser o problema, mas nada fez funcionar.

OBS: no Request Payload o id vem certo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pq está usando desta forma: `data:JSON.stringify ({'id': idArea}),` quando poderia usar assim: `data: {id: idArea},`?

Comment: @Sam na verdade eu estava testando várias formas, acabou que quando fiz a pergunta estava sssim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, não sei se é uma boa prática, mas enfim, pra quem estiver com o mesmo problema:

```
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),1);
print_r($data['id']);
```